# How to add value to a null property in laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to add some custom object where a property is null. But it seems it doesn't assign anything and still get null.

here is what I am trying..

```
foreach($tree as $k => $d){ 
     if(!$d->home){
         $obj = [
              'teamName' => "Winner of Match $d->tempHomeTeam",
               'player1' => [
                    'firstName' => 'Player1',
                    'lastName' => '',
                    

                ],
                'player2' => [
                    'firstName' => 'Player2',
                    'lastName' => '',
                ],
            ];

            $tree[$k]->home = $obj;
            // or 
            $d->home = $obj;


        }
    }
```

how can I add this custom obj to home eager loaded property?

Comment: Where are you seeing that it's null? Also, I'm assuming there's no setter defined for `home` that may be interfering?

Comment: it shows null.. some item has values already but I need to custom object in case they are null. But still shows null

I am seeing null when returning the whole array after the loop.

Comment: Can you add an accessor for `home` to your model instead? See Laravel docs for [get{Attribute}Attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: thank you. will try